# How can I keep SSH connection alive?

Tags: 14.04, ssh, connection, tunnel

I use Ubuntu 14.04 on my server and I've added these lines into `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`: *(as it's mentioned [here](https://patrickmn.com/aside/how-to-keep-alive-ssh-sessions/))*

```
ServerAliveInterval 300
ServerAliveCountMax 2
ClientAliveInterval 300
ClientAliveCountMax 2
```

Now my server is broken `:(`. I cannot connect to it through neither regular SSH connection nor tunneling:

Regular SSH Connection:

[image]

Tunneling To MySQL For Accessing Databases On The Server

[image]

I really have valuable data into server's databases without any backup. Any idea?

Comment: If you don't have any means of remote access other than SSH, you'll have to get someone to physically login to it (or use the hypervisor console, if it's a VM).

Comment: @muru There is an option on my access panel named "insert VM-tool". Do I click on it?

Comment: since I have no idea what your hypervisor is, I can't say. Ask your local system administrator.

Comment: @muru I asked. It is vMware

Comment: You should always have at least one backup of all valuable data.

Comment: @muru The problem resolved ... *(using VNC)*

Answer (score 1):

using mosh your connection is always alive.
Mosh takes all the security benefits of SSH and builds upon it a greater tolerance to poor network conditions and roaming connections. It also increases responsiveness and lowers bandwidth usage by only communicating state changes to the currently visible screen region, rather than transmitting complete buffers.

Comment: How can I make a mosh connection?

Comment: check this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-mosh-on-a-vps

Comment: Well the problem is I cannot access the server using Putty or whatever *(SSH Connection)*. So I cannot install mosh.